# OnApplyTemplate() is not called, stuff in Template property doesn't show up either

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, templates, controls

I have the following class:

```
namespace Controls
{
    public class DropDownButton : Control
    {
        public DropDownButton()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(DropDownButton);
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
        }
    }
}
```

And in XAML:

```
<Style TargetType="Controls:DropDownButton">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="202"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Button Content="Button1">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="65"/>
</Style>
```

I have two problems (possibly related): The button in the xaml is not being displayed in the control and the control is not having its OnApplyTemplate() function called at all. The only thing the control seems to be responsive to is setting its dimensions...

Comment: Are you really setting the template to a Button rather than a ControlTemplate containing a Button?

Comment: `Template` expects a control template, yet in your `Setter.Value` you have a `Button`. I'd expect an exception of some kind.

Comment: oooh, I tried wrapping it in ControlTemplate tags and it worked.. I wasn't getting exceptions before though which is odd...

Comment: So did that answer the question? If so i could post it as an answer...

Comment: yep go ahead and I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Template` is lacking its `ControlTemplate` element:

```xml
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate> <!-- This -->
            <Button Content="Button1">
                <!-- ... -->
            </Button>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```